# Syntax error, unexpected ; expecting )

Tags: php

Tengo el problema con el siguiente código PHP:

```
$urlcontent = '
<?php
$servername = ".'$servername'.";
$mcpelist = ".'$mcpelist'.";
$longlink = ".'$longlink'.";
$alias = ".'$alias'.";
include ("../configs/variables.php");
include ("../configs/template.php");
?>';
```

---

@AngelFragaParodi o quien pueda ayudarme...

Lo cambié a

```
 // Content of every shortened URL
    $urlcontent = '<?php
    $servername =  "'.$servername.'";
    $mcpelist =  "'.$mcpelist.'"
    $longlink =  "'.$longlink.'"
    $alias =  "'.$alias.'"
    include ('../configs/variables.php');
    include ('../configs/template.php');
    ?>';
```

y no funciona.

Comment: Otra pregunta de las muchas relacionadas con el acortador de URLs.

Comment: @Josue Federico , has vuelto establecer mal las comillas. Te actualizo la respuesta

Comment: Josué o como te llames de verdad, si aceptaras como buena alguna respuesta de las muchas preguntas que has hecho, no estaría de más.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas Josue, el problema consiste en la concatenación de tus cadenas con las variables PHP. Es decir para concatenar variables en PHP se usa el punto.

Para lograrlo correctamente debes abrir y cerrar correctamente las comillas en cada momento.

Una nota a tener en cuenta es que en PHP el uso de comillas dobles permite el uso en su interior de variables PHP sin tener que abrir y cerrar las comillas y usar el punto.

En tu caso empiezas usando comillas simples , con lo cual necesitas  cerrar y abrir de nuevo para concatenar. Un ejemplo a lo que has hecho es :

```
 $miVariable = '<?php  $servername = ".'$servername'."; ?>';
```

Esto estaría mal , siendo la forma adecuada:

```
 $miVariable = '<?php  $servername = "'.$servername.'"; ?>';
```

Cambiando el lugar de los puntos se podrá concatenar correctamente.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Josue, al usar de nuevo comillas en el include vuelves a cerrar el string concatenado, exactamente aquí:

```
include ('../configs/variables.php');
include ('../configs/template.php');
```

Cambia esta parte por esto:

```
include ("../configs/variables.php");
include ("../configs/template.php");
```

Te recomiendo usar un editor de código con resaltado de sintaxis para que te indique estos errores de forma visual y puedas corregirlos en el mismo momento.

Un ejemplo de lo que te ha pasado es:

```
 <?php 
   $miEdad = 10 ;
   $miFrase = "Tengo ";
   $finalComillasDobles = $miFrase." $miEdad años";
   echo $finalComillasDobles;
   $finalComillasSimples = $miFrase.' '.$miEdad.' años';
   echo $finalComillasSimples ;
   $finalComplejo ="Hola amigo. '$miFrase $miEdad años'.".'Hasta luego ';
   echo $finalComplejo ;
?>
```

Este ejemplo daría una salida de :

```
"Tengo 10 años"
"Tengo 10 años"
"Hola amigo. 'Tengo 10 años'.Hasta luego "
```

En definitiva el uso de comillas simple y dobles es indiferente con la única diferencia de que las dobles permiten usar nuestras variables sin concatenar, si usamos ambas solo tenemos que saber bien cuando cerrar y abrir cada una.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que escapar las comillas de los includes. Pon `\'` en vez de `'`.

Pero yo te recomendaría que cambiases el diseño del programa para no generar el código PHP tú mismo. Utiliza algún *template engine* de los muchos que hay.